# Drawing a colored circle

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to draw a simple colored circle on the screen with cocos2d, but everything I draw comes out white.
I tried glColor4f and glColor4ub but neither one works, even though they were used here to draw colored primitives: http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/tests/drawPrimitivesTest.m?r=1813

These are examples straight out of their code, but it's just giving me a white circle and a white line.

```
-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

    glColor4f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glLineWidth(2.0f);
    ccDrawLine(ccp(10,100),ccp(50,79));

    glLineWidth(16);
    glColor4ub(0, 255, 0, 255);
    ccDrawCircle( ccp(200,  200), 100, 0, 10, NO);

}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but don't forget to call [super draw].

Comment: Ah right. Doesn't solve my problem though.

Comment: What version of cocos2d are you using?

Comment: cocos2d v2.0.0-beta is what /cocos2d/cocos2d.m tells me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cocos2d 2.0 uses OpenGLES 2.0. `glColor4f` no longer exists. To change the draw color you can use

```
ccDrawColor4F(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: How do I use that? Adding it (say replacing the glColor4f line) gives me a `Implicit declaration of function 'ccDrawColor4F' is invalid in C99` warning and causes a crash when run

Comment: There might be something wrong with your project setup. It should just work in cocos2d 2.0. Open up CCDrawingPrimitives.h and see what you can find in there.

Comment: Upgrade to cocos2d 2.0 stable. If you're using "beta" which I suppose means the first 2.0 beta then those functions don't exist in your version.

Comment: Upgraded to 2.0 stable and it fixed the problem. Thanks!